# Customize dbstop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging

Is it possible to add a customized `dbstop` condition to Matlab?

Recently I found myself with out of bounds values in multiple variables, one way to track down the first occurance of this would be to set a conditional breakpoint on each line where these values are updated. However, I hope there is an easier way to do this.

I have recently had to track down a `NaN` which was fairly trivial due to:

```
dbstop if naninf
```

Hence I hope that it is possible to get something like:

```
dbstop if anything outside myBound
```

or

```
dbstop if myVariable outside myBound
```

I would of course be willing to take the performance hit that one may expect.

Comment: Can't you just use the following version of `dbstop`: `DBSTOP in FILESPEC if EXPRESSION`?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you need to specify the (each) location for the breakpoint. If you don't specify it, Matlab assumes the first line of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using the form "DBSTOP in FILESPEC if EXPRESSION" of `dbstop` is that it sets a breakpoint only at the *first* line of the file. A solution is to use the form "DBSTOP in FILESPEC at LINENO if EXPRESSION" to set a breakpoint at *each* line.

Consider the following example script, saved on a file called `testfile.m`.

```
clear all
for m = 1:10;
    k = 2*m
end
```

Say we want to stop if variable `k` exceeds the value `6`. We first automatically set the breakpoints in all lines of this file:

```
file = 'testfile.m';
varname = 'k';
expression = 'k>6'; %// it should be 'exist(''k'')&&k>6', but that's added later

%// Determine number of lines of file:
fid = fopen('testfile.m');
cont = 1;
nlines = 0;
while cont
    readline = fgetl(fid);
    cont = ~isequal(readline,-1);
    nlines = nlines + cont;
end
fclose(fid);

%// Set breakpoint at each line. We need eval for this
for n = 1:nlines
    eval(['dbstop in ' file ' at ' num2str(n) ' if ( exist(''' varname...
        ''') && ( ' expression ' ) )'])
end
```

Now, after running the above (check that every line of `testfile.m` has a yellow breakpoint), run `testfile` and check values when it stops:

[image]

This is admittedly a little cumbersome if you have several variables or files. Also, I'm not sure how many simultaneous breakpoints Matlab supports (we are using one for each program line).

Answer (score 4):

If you use the editor, you can set a stop as normal, right-click on it, select "set/modify condition" and enter the condition (the stop will turn from red to yellow).

From command line, you can use

```
dbstop in file if expression
dbstop in file at location if expression

e.g.
dbstop in myFile at 200 if (~isempty(var) && var > 3)
```

as mentioned by @LuisMendo.

The second option may be more useful, since the first one seems to be only evaluated at the start of the file. In other words, it doesn't seem to be possible to have a similarly generic expression as `dbstop if naninf` that checks for certain values across an entire file.

Comment: I suppose I may be able to write a wrapper around this that 1. Finds all occurances of myVar (or just choose all lines) 2. Put a conditional breakpoint on those lines. Still not as powerfull as `dbstop if naninf` as that works across files and variables, but perhaps sufficient.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: You need to make sure that `myVar` is defined when the break point occurs, so you do need to regexp for at least the first occurrence.

Comment: What does that "at 200" mean?

Comment: @user42459: it means at line 200

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box - you could write a class to hold your variable. There you could have a customized setter that will raise a warning if you violate boundaries. `dbstop if warning` should then be enough.

Comment: Would this be possible without touching the code and the inputs?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without adjusting the code. One would need to override the `=` operator.