# Stop or pause running MatLab whenever there is division by 0 or Inf value occurs

Tags: matlab

When there are so many m-files with so many calculations, tracking why this and that went wrong is really a big task.

Often it just turns out that somewhere in the code there was division by 0, or value of Inf saved for some variable.

I want to make this easy to check. One way is to write

```
if a == Inf
   display('a is infinite')
   keyboard
end
```

If I add things like this everytime for every variable, it will work but it will be messy.

Can I make MatLab stop or pause or pop up a warning message if some variable is Inf in the process of running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matlab has a nice [debugging suite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) for a number of on-the-fly conditions.
In particular, the command<sup>1</sup>

```
dbstop if naninf
```

which will pause execution a line after a `NaN` or `Inf` condition is found.  An example is given [on the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#buz52rg).  The only potential downside of using this feature is that the pause occurs if any variables are initialized as `NaN` or `Inf`, which some codes do (to my confusion).

[`dbstop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) does have a more pinpoint and potentially robust system of pausing execution, but I think the `naninf` option combined with good tests is an excellent place to start for general development.

---

<sup>1</sup> The same behavior can be invoked from the GUI by going to Breakpoints > More Error and Warning Handling Options > NaN or Inf and selecting the correct radio button.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, in my current project, having NaN is very normal while Inf is definitely wrong. How can I make it stop or pause when Inf occurs but not stop or pause when NaN occurs?

Comment: If there is some MatLab built-in m-file that makes "dbstop if naninf" works, then probably I can edit the m-file to make it stop only for Inf. Is this possible?

Comment: @user42459 For more pinpoint control, I would [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996074/customize-dbstop-in-matlab) for a starting point, and you may need to do more work.  `NaN`s and `Inf`s are both exceptions in IEEE arithmetic, so Matlab treats them the same for its default error handling options.  Unfortunately, some coders end up using `NaN`s explicitly while they should be really only be generated by calculation.

Comment: Hi, last time I couldn't understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996074/customize-dbstop-in-matlab and right now I have the same problem bu still can't understand. I am really a novice. But could I ask you if it is at least possible to make "dbstop if inf" which stops only when there is inf in the workspace?