# Stop/pause MatLab execution for any underflow and overflow

Tags: matlab

Related questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656633/matlab-thinks-small-number-as-0-large-number-as-inf

[Stop or pause running MatLab whenever there is division by 0 or Inf value occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635406/stop-or-pause-running-matlab-whenever-there-is-division-by-0-or-inf-value-occurs)

My project entails a lot of m-files which take a lot of time.

So when there is a mistake/error in the code, it's hard to debug.

This time, problem was caused by arithmetic underflow and overflow. My variable calculated

```
(1e-108)^3
```

which MatLab thinks is just 0. Underflow problem.

It took me so long time to find out that my project was stuck because of this underflow error.

If I had a way to stop or pause MatLab whenever it encounters ANY underflow or overflow problem at ANY m-file and ANY function I am running, it would have taken me no time to find that this was what was causing all the trouble.

I found that there is

```
dbstop if naninf
```

I am hoping there is something like

```
dbstop if underoverflow
```

but I couldn't find such thing.. Should I create (if it is possible) a new kind of dbstop command?

Comment: Use a [conditional breakpoint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html#buvvmfu-1)

Comment: @excaza Thanks. But I want to achieve it globally. I have main.m which has a lot of functions associated by a.m, b.m and so on. And they are long. So rather than creating conditional breakpoints one by one, I want to add a line that causes MatLab to stop or pause whenever there is underflow or overflow.